# Is there a way to return an array into another array?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to return an array into another array. 
I have a multidimensional array which I am using a method `combineArrays(Comparable[][] x)` to combine into another 1D array.

Normally I'd just create the 1D array in a higher scope, but I've painfully learned that Comparable arrays need a dimension when initialized and the `combineArrays()` is responsible for determining the size of the mutliarray.

Please be kind, I'm not done yet.
The purpose of the program itself is to accept an array of objects and find a common list of object which exist in each row. The trick is the `findCommonElements()` must do so in either O(nlogn) or O(n) time

```
/*
 * combs through the original array to find the shortest row which must hold
 * the least # of common objects
 */
public static int findSmallestRow(Comparable[][] queries) {
    int array_length = 0;
    int indexOfMaster = 0;
    array_length = queries[0].length; // sets variable to initial arrays row
                                        // length
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) { // iterates through each row
                                                // comparing size of each
                                                // row
        if (queries[i].length <= array_length) { // ensures the 1st row is,
                                                    // at minimum, the
                                                    // master array
            array_length = queries[i].length;
            indexOfMaster = i;

        }

    }
    return indexOfMaster;
}

public static void findCommonElements(Comparable[][] queries){
    Comparable[] new_query = combineArray(queries);
    for(int a = 0; a<new_query.length; a++){
        System.out.println(new_query[a]);
    }
    //Arrays.sort(new_query);
    int query_length = new_query.length;
    int masterIndex = findSmallestRow(queries);
    Comparable extracted[] = new Comparable[queries[masterIndex].length];
    System.arraycopy(queries[masterIndex], 0, extracted, 0,
            extracted.length);
    Comparable[] intermediate_query = new Comparable[masterIndex];

    int nonquery_length = extracted.length;
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int query_index = 0;
    int nonquery_index = 0;
    int i =0;
    int j = 0;



    while(i < nonquery_length && j < query_length){
        if(extracted[nonquery_index].compareTo(new_query[query_index])>0){
            query_index++;
        }
        if(extracted[nonquery_index].compareTo(new_query[query_index])<0){
            nonquery_index++;
        }
        if(extracted[nonquery_index].compareTo(new_query[query_index])==0){
            counter++;
            if(counter == queries.length){
                intermediate_query[counter2] = extracted[nonquery_index];
                counter2++;
            }

        }
    }
    Comparable common_list[] = new Comparable[counter2];

    for(int k = 0; k<counter2; k++){
        common_list[k] = intermediate_query[k];
        System.out.println(common_list[i]);
    }

}

//gets size of query array, even if not uniform
public static Comparable[] combineArray(Comparable[][]queries){
    int length = queries.length;
    ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i< length; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k<queries[i].length; k++){
            rows.add("");
        }
    }

    int query_size = rows.size();

    Comparable[] new_query = new Comparable[query_size];
    int new_query_counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i< length; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k<queries[i].length; k++){
            new_query[new_query_counter] = queries[i][k];
        }
    }

return new_query;
}
```

Comment: Either sample input/output or more code would increase your chances of getting a meaningful answer (and not getting closed).

Comment: There's nothing special about Comparable here. Yes, you'll need to work out how big your array needs to be - or put all the elements into an `ArrayList` letting that grow as it needs to, then call `toArray`. Where exactly are you stuck? Is this "combining" just a matter or flattening?

Comment: Using an arraylist defeats the point of comparables

Comment: Increment new_query_counter in `new_query[new_query_counter] = queries[i][k];`. You are only setting the first element...

Comment: This is an awful lot of code for a simple problem. Why don't you create sets from the array rows and compute their intersection?

Comment: @laune Thank You. Can't believe I didn't catch that. sets have never been a strong point of mine, but I'll have to look that up. As it is I think that might be a bit difficult because if the shortest row contains duplicates I've been instructed that I have to keep them

Comment: Added a proposal for using a multiset which should take care of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This computes the set intersection of all the rows of the array.

```
public static Set<Comparable<?>> common( Comparable<?>[][] a ){
    Set<Comparable<?>> inter = new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( a[0] ) );
    for( int i = 1; i < a.length; ++i ){
        inter.retainAll( new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( a[i] ) ) );
    }
    return inter;
}
```

It is possible that the original idea is to retain repeated elements, i.e., if there are two 'x' in each row, the result should also contain two 'x'. The short solution given hear uses sets, which do not store repetition of equal elements. - But here is a library where you find HashMultiSet, and the code will remain basically the same except for the types of inter and result.

```
 import org.apache.commons.collections4.multiset.HashMultiSet;
```